# Adding a series filled with Rolling count, sum or mean

Tags: python, pandas, countif, rolling-computation

Stimulated by another post, my story is:
I have this df

```
   col
0  B
1  B
2  A
3  A
4  A
5  B
```

and i need this output

```
   col col_frequencies
0  B   1
1  B   2
2  A   1 
3  A   2
4  A   3
5  B   3
```

# Value in row 5 is the update of that in row 2. I do not want the counter of frequencies be resetted

Something like a countif in excel.

Thanks in advance from a total beginner,
G.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in two stages:

1. Group all rows with same col value. This can be done using `groupby()`.
2. Get index of each row in the new group. You do this with `cumcount()` (which start from zero, so you want to add +1 to it)

All in one:

```py
df['col_frequencies'] = df.groupby(['col']).cumcount()+1;
```

for example (sorry for laziness in columns name)

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(['B', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B'])
print(df)
df['Col'] = df.groupby([0]).cumcount()+1;
```

output:

```
    0   Cola
0   B   1
1   B   2
2   A   1
3   A   2
4   A   3
5   B   3
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the value_count function of pandas, to get the frequency of any data point.

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your problem:-

Let say your data frame name is `df`.

```
res = {}
r = []
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['col'] in res:
        res[row['col']] += 1
        r.append(res[row['col']])
    else:
        res[row['col']] = 1
        r.append(res[row['col']])

df['col_frequencies'] = r
```

The output will be:-

```
   col col_frequencies
0  B   1
1  B   2
2  A   1 
3  A   2
4  A   3
5  B   3
```